# How to use OR operator with regular expression?

Tags: xml, regex

I'm using a regex expression to catch an ad id from a landing page's URL using a specific parameter that comes before the ad id.

i have an issue with one of my clients that used a different parameter for his URLs on the same day for different ads.

This is the expression that relates to the 1st parameter:

```
<Read Var="destUrl" Field='DestinationUrl' Regex='(\bp=edgetrackerid_(?{edgetrackerid}\w+)\b)'/>
```

And this is the expression that relates to the 2nd parameter:

```
 <Read Var="destUrl" Field='DestinationUrl' Regex='(\bp=edgetrackerid(?{edgetrackerid}\w+)\b)'/>
```

But when downloading the report it will only relate to the one I've put first. 
How can I fix this? 
I want to say - if the first parameter is not there, then use the second one (without the underscore _)

Thanks

Comment: Can't see the regular expressions

Comment: `\bp=edgetrackerid_?(?{edgetrackerid}\w+)\b)` with the optional underscore?

Comment: yes, sometimes it will appear in the url like this: edgetrackerid_12345 and sometimes it will look like this: edgetrackerid12345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `_?` which means zero or one underscores.

So your regex will be

```
(\bp=edgetrackerid_?(?{edgetrackerid}\w+)\b)
```

Comment: @user1508682 Are you sure the regex is correct? Because I am not sure if `(? ... )` is a valid capture group.

Comment: yes it does work for me it the parameter includes edgeidtrecker_ (with underscore)

Comment: hi! thanks! in a second try it did worked for me with the ? mark and also with a * mark. THANKS!! :)